# How does Apache Flink handles registered timers state? Does it store/recover them? for both `Event Time` and `Processing Time` chrasteristics?

Tags: apache-flink

Apache Flink has a time-service and let developers register time based events, and be notified on those events (base on processing time or event time)! but I don't understand how it works when Apache Flink take checkpoints and recovers it's state from those snapshots!

- Does it store & recover its timer states?
- I can guess how it work for event-time! (by storing watermarks) but what about processing time?
- If it doesn't store timers, then a failure-recovery will not be successful, till we are going to lost all time-based events/states, and that means that time-windows will not function correctly! Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of Flink's timers are saved as managed Flink state, and restored during the fault-recovery process. All processing-time timers that should have fired during the outage will fire immediately upon being restored, and event-time timers will fire naturally, as watermarks arrive.

The only thing that isn't handled perfectly is that the operators do not checkpoint their current watermarks. If the sources are reasonably active this won't generally be noticeable, but if you have a nearly idle source, then this could cause delayed firings of event-time timers.